# how to make svg object clickable link?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

i want to scroll to html id tag using  img/1.png   image in svg file

my Html Block

```
<object width="1024" height="597" data="svg/index/1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="pdf1" style="width:1024px; height:597px; background-color:white; -moz-transform:scale(1); z-index: 0;">
</object>
```

my Svg file  1.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <defs>
          <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
             .g1_1{
                  fill: #8FEFCA;
                  fill-opacity: 0.71000695;
             }
             .g2_1{
                  fill: #8EDBED;
                  fill-opacity: 0.5399929;
             }
          ]]></style>
     </defs>
     <path d="M1024,597L0,597L0,320l1024,0l0,277Z" class="g1_1" />
     <path d="M455,597l569,0L1024,0l-9,0Z" class="g2_1" />
     <a xlink:href="#p2">
           <image x="690" y="290" width="25" height="24" xlink:href="img/1.png" />
     </a>
</svg>
```

i tried to use jquery inside svg file but jquery scroll function which i declared in html file is not called

```
<div id = "p2"> scroll here </div>
```

> Test URL : http://cabitsystems.com/svgtest/tt.html

Comment: Modern browsers can handle SVG in `<img>` tags. Have you tried that instead of using `<object>`?

Comment: `SVG`s are objects on their own, and `jquery` can't access their insides or calculate `offset`s within them. You could try with pure javascript, although I doubt this would work since the elements inside an SVG are offset compared to the viewbox, size of the svg, etc... SVGs should not be used for this purpose.

Comment: Here is test URL : http://cabitsystems.com/svgtest/tt.html    ya i tried with object

Comment: Also i have another idea , can i place html image over svg ???

Comment: @Shikkediel it will make entire svg object clickable , am interesting in just arrow  img/1.png as you can see test URL

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the special conditions - why I removed the comment. ;-)

Comment: Why not make the whole svg inline with the HTML? Much easier to add event listeners that way.

Answer (score 0):

i Solve this another way .... i extracted image from svg file and then put it over svg using position

html block

```
<a href="#p2" onclick="alert('hiii')">
    <img src="svg/index/img/1.png" id="p1x" x="690" y="290" z="300" width="25" height="24">
</a>
```

and little css

```
 a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* padding: 27px; */
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  left: 685px;
  top: 200px;
  position: absolute;
```

Comment: Although this works it beats all the purpose of having an SVG in the first place, no? You defined all in pixels, so this wont scale like an SVG would/is intended to do.

Comment: ya i agree , will have to find better solution , but for now it was emergency :)